# How can I fix getting the error window is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, sveltekit

How can I fix getting the error window is not defined when using firebase in my sveltekit project I cant put it on mount because of other reasons and am trying to get around it? any ideas or is there a way for me to put the initialization in on mount and still send the data outside of mount

```
 <script>
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
      import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
      import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
      import { onMount } from 'svelte';
      import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
      
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      let song = 'song';
        
      const firebaseConfig = {
     
      };
    
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      const db = getFirestore(app);
      async function sendSong(){
      try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "songs"), {
          title: {song},
          atist: "test"
        });
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
      }
      </script>
      <input bind:value={song}>
   
      
      <style>
      </style>
```

Comment: You should really fix whatever prevents you from using `onMount`...

Comment: @H.B. when i wrap everything but the function in onmount it says cannot find name "db" I have tried fixing this by putting let db; but it still doesn't work

Comment: You have to put the `let db` outside the `onMount` if that was not clear and then assign that inside `onMount`. You must avoid declaring another `db` inside `onMount` otherwise the outer one gets shadowed and will not be affected.

Comment: @H.B. I put the let db outside of onMount yes, Im really new to this so it would helpful if you could provide the code like a jsfiddle or something to help me understand better

Comment: [Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/7f444987ec214509a574980ea7bc916f?version=3.49.0)

Comment: @H.B. ok I guess I had that figured out and had it right but forgot to check console logs now its a new problem, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318236/how-to-stop-error-adding-document-firebaseerror-expected-first-argument-to-col)

Comment: Fixed it! and now I feel stupid, thanks for all the great help @H.B.

Comment: You are welcome. Please either answer your own question or delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up working for me

```
<script>
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import { collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

let song
let artist
let db
onMount(() => {
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
        //redacted
    }

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app)
    db = getFirestore(app)
})

async function sendSong() {
    try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'songs'), {
            song : { song },
            atist: { artist },
        })
        console.log('Document written with ID: ', docRef.id)
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Error adding document: ', e)
    }
}
</script>
<div class="main">
    <h1 class="text-primary">Submit a song</h1>
    <input class="margin" placeholder="song" bind:value={song}>
    <input class="margin" placeholder="artist" bind:value={artist}>
    <button on:click={sendSong} id="send-button" type="submit" class="margin sub button primary is-full-width "
    >Submit Form
    </button>
</div>
```